# When does connectedness imply path-connectedness

Tags: general-topology, connectedness

In a locally path-connected space connectedness and path connectedness are equivalent. What is the minimal condition we would impose on a topological space to get the same result?

**EDIT:**
This question is closed for clarity. The question is very clear. I will restate it, "What is the most relaxed topological condition that implies equivalence of connectedness and path connectedness?". Obviously, it's an open question, since it has no asnwer.

Comment: My guess is that there is probably no minimal condition.

Comment: @pete Would you please elaborate on that?